# Which technologies are advised to use for developing the following project?

Tags: html, web-services, rest, single-page-application

Two years ago I developed an admin panel using winFroms that is used to configure different settings for specific users, create/remove users etc. This information is retrieved and saved to a SQL Database server.

I want to make this panel accessible through web browsers. I already have a REST API that will communicate with the database.

My question is: which technologies are the best to make this panel?
I've come across WebForms, MVC, HTML with Angular, jQuery etc., or with SPA.

I would appreciate it if someone can enlighten me with this matter. I know its not really a specific programmatic question, but there are so many different approaches that is difficult to find the right or best way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already know a lot of .NET so if I was you I would just use a WebForms or MVC project and then call some jQuery on the api to handle the CRUD operations. But if you wanna try something completely new then use Angular.